# MySQL prepared statement in a stored procedure not behaving as expected

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have this MySQL Stored Procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`dbuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `getTranslatedAnswer`(IN questionDesc VARCHAR(2500), col VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    SET @paramVal = questionDesc;
    SET @str = CONCAT('SELECT C.',col,' AS `answer`, D.',col,' AS `message` 
        FROM `option_group` A 
            INNER JOIN `questions_answers` B ON A.`option_id` = B.`option_id` 
            INNER JOIN `answers` C ON B.`answers_id` = C.`answers_id` 
            INNER JOIN  `chat_message` D ON A.`option_group_id` = D.`option_group_id` 
        WHERE UPPER(`A`.',col,') = ? LIMIT 1');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @paramVal;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

The above code when called using

```
call getTranslatedAnswer('我可以在机场买到预付SIM卡吗？','zh_chs');
```

will return 0 rows. Compared to as when I call the bare SQL below

```
SELECT C.zh_chs AS `answer`, D.zh_chs AS `message` 
        FROM `option_group` A 
            INNER JOIN `questions_answers` B ON A.`option_id` = B.`option_id` 
            INNER JOIN `answers` C ON B.`answers_id` = C.`answers_id` 
            INNER JOIN  `chat_message` D ON A.`option_group_id` = D.`option_group_id` 
        WHERE UPPER(`A`.`zh_chs`) = '我可以在机场买到预付SIM卡吗？' LIMIT 1;
```

it returns 1 row. Am I missing something here? How do I debug this? Please advise, thanks!

Comment: You seem to have some encoding problem. Try to use `(IN questionDesc VARCHAR(2500) character set utf8, ...`.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks man, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I could be remembering wrong, but I seem to recall `execute` not actually returning results as you expecting it to.
What happens if you try something like this?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`dbuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `getTranslatedAnswer`(IN questionDesc VARCHAR(2500), col VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    SET @paramVal = questionDesc;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `t_getTranslatedAnswer`;
    SET @str = CONCAT('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `t_getTranslatedAnswer`
        SELECT C.',col,' AS `answer`, D.',col,' AS `message` 
        FROM `option_group` A 
            INNER JOIN `questions_answers` B ON A.`option_id` = B.`option_id` 
            INNER JOIN `answers` C ON B.`answers_id` = C.`answers_id` 
            INNER JOIN  `chat_message` D ON A.`option_group_id` = D.`option_group_id` 
        WHERE UPPER(`A`.',col,') = ? LIMIT 1');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @str;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @paramVal;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SELECT * FROM `t_getTranslatedAnswer`;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `t_getTranslatedAnswer`;
END
```

Comment: Thanks, it is returning fine it's just that when it is Chinese then it won't return any result, sorry I missed to include that part if detail.